# Make only one instance of the same field appearing in a JSP page editable

Tags: javascript, jquery

experts

Here I have my code

There can be multiple channels for a particular event , e.g 
For **

- **Event** 1

  Channel

  - **Event** 2

  Channel

**
Initially the Channel values are same against each event now when a user wants to edit a channel value say for event 1 , the edited value gets reflected in event 2 channel as well,
 **which should not happen the edited value should get reflected against that particular event only.**

The code to display the channels against event in a jsp is

```
<div class="container-fluid left-padded">
<input data-focus-div="#" type="hidden" value="${divId}">
<div class="container-fluid">
<h4><spring:message code="event.details" />:</h4>

<c:forEach var="sendStatusForm" items="${eventStatusForm.sendStatusForms}">
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class ="span2">
        <label><spring:message code="event.channels"></spring:message>:&nbsp; </label> 
        </div>
        <div class = "span3">
        <div class="textbox">   
            <div class="textVal">${eventStatusForm.channels}</div>
            <div id="pencil" class="span3">
            <img src="/static/img/image1.png" alt="Edit">
             </div>
            <div id="save" class="span3">
            <img src="/static/img/image2.png" alt="Save">
            </div>
            <div id="close" class="span3">
            <img src="/static/img/image3.png" alt="Close">
            </div>
        </div>  
        </div>
    </DIV>
</c:forEach>
</DIV>
</div>
```

The Jquery code is

```
var textValue = "";
$('#pencil').on('click', function(){
    textValue =  $('.textVal').text();
    $('.textVal').html("<input type='textbox' id='textVal' value='" + textValue + "' />");
    $(this).hide();
    $('#save, #close').show();
});

$('#save').on('click', function(){
    $('.textVal').text($('#textVal').val());
    $(this).hide();
    $('#close').hide();
    $('#pencil').show();
});

$('#close').on('click', function(){
    $('.textVal').text(textValue);
    $(this).hide();
    $('#save').hide();
    $('#pencil').show();
});
```

Finally the CSS code is

```
<style type="text/css">
.textbox {
    height:24px;
    width:90px;
    line-height:22px;
    padding:3px

}
#textVal {
    width:35px;
    margin-right:5px
}
.icons {
    float:left;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
#save, #close {
    display:none;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    float:left
}
.textVal {
    float:left;
    width:35px;
    height:20px;
    margin-right:5px
}
#pencil {
    display:block
}
</style>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the same field" - multiple DOM elements with the same class? Also what do you have right now for jQuery code that's making all instances editable?

Comment: I have added the code as above , please have a look , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, be careful when using id attributes inside loops as you will generate invalid HTML markup. Id attributes must be unique in a page, use classes for your elements instead.

```
<c:forEach var="sendStatusForm" items="${eventStatusForm.sendStatusForms}">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class ="span2">
        <label><spring:message code="event.channels"></spring:message>:&nbsp; </label> 
        </div>
        <div class = "span3">
        <div class="textbox">   
            <div class="textVal">${eventStatusForm.channels}</div>
            <div class="pencil span3">
            <img src="/static/img/image1.png" alt="Edit">
             </div>
            <div class="save span3">
            <img src="/static/img/image2.png" alt="Save">
            </div>
            <div class="close span3">
            <img src="/static/img/image3.png" alt="Close">
            </div>
        </div>  
        </div>
    </DIV>
</c:forEach>
```

Now you need to target only the specific element in your row when making the edits so use `.siblings()` to filter the elements in each event:

```
var textValue = "";
$('.pencil').on('click', function(){
    textValue =  $(this).siblings('.textVal').text();
    $(this).siblings('.textVal').html("<input type='text' id='textVal' value='" + textValue + "' />");
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('.save, .close').show();
});

$('.save').on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings('.textVal').html($(this).siblings('.textVal').find(':text').val());
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('.close').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.pencil').show();
});

$('.close').on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings('.textVal').html(textValue)
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('.save').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.pencil').show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works but the another issue i See is that when the page gets loaded , I see all the images i.e image 1 , image 2 and image 3 against each channels ,  instead only images 1 should appear against the channels initially , the image 2 and image 3 appear only after a click on image 1

Comment: Update your CSS, replace `#save, #close, #pencil` for `.save, .close, .pencil` or hide them with javascript on document ready `$('.save,.close').hide();`

Comment: Also I updated the answer to make sure it returns the correct value when multiple edits are open